# query_string filter inside a nested filter throws an error

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, filtering

In this example I've placed a full query example that's been paired down to the non-working portion that has me stuck.

Basically we have a document that has a nested document type under datailItems and trying to do a query_string filter against a field in that nested document fails.  I take the same portion and run it against a non-nested field and it works.  So obviously I'm doing something wrong.

The error I receive is `nested: QueryParsingException[[******] [_na] filter malformed, must start with start_object]`

So, What is the proper way to do this?

Some caveats.  The "and"s are used for further filter requirements that contain bools, ranges, etc... I have stripped out those additional reqs for this example.

```
{
    "size" : 1,
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "filter" : {
                "and" : [{
                        "nested" : {
                            "path" : "detailItems",
                            "filter" : {
                                "and" : [{
                                        "query" : {
                                            "query_string" : {
                                                "detailItems.name" : {
                                                    "query" : "mastersettings",
                                                    "minimum_should_match" : 1
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take the `query_string` part only, including the field `detailItems.name` and test it outside that large query. Something like this `{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "detailItems",
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "fields": [
            "detailItems.name"
          ],
          "query": "mastersettings",
          "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Ok, it looks like I have to take it completely out of a nested filter to work

    `{
        "size" : 1,
        "query" : {
            "filtered" : {
                "filter" : {
                    "query" : {
                        "query_string" : {
                            "detailItems.name" : {
                                "query" : "mastersettings",
                                "minimum_should_match" : 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [query_string](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax) in the OP is not syntactically correct, below is an example of how the query string could be re-written:

```
  "size" : 1,
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "filter" : {
                "and" : [{
                        "nested" : {
                            "path" : "detailItems",
                            "filter" : {
                                "and" : [{
                                        "query" : {
                                            "query_string" : {
                                                "fields": [
                                                   "detailItems.name" 
                                                ], 
                                                "query" : "mastersettings",
                                                "minimum_should_match" : 1

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yah I got that to run myself but I couldn't actually get it to return results.  Why would my original work outside the nested context and not inside it?

Comment: While this didn't solve my goal, it is the solution to the problem as stated.  Thanks @keety